# modular operator

Tags: matrices, operator-algebras

I could calculate a modular operator $Δ$ for a state $τ_α(x_{ij})= αx_{11}+(1-α)x_{22}(0<α<1)$.
But, I cannot understand an automorphism $σ_t(x)＝Δ^{it}(x)Δ^{-it}$ of $M_2(\mathbb{C})$.

For example, suppose that $x=(x_{ij}) \in M_2(\mathbb{C})$.
Then how can $σ_t(x)$ be written as matrix form?

Comment: This is basic linear algebra, but would you share your result for $\Delta$ with us so that one can give you a concrete answer?